# Prolog - nodes, leaves, symmetry

Tags: prolog

I've been trying to understand how exactly the following query gets evaluated in Prolog:

```
reflection(leaf,leaf).
reflection(node(S1,S2),node(T2,T1)) :-
   reflection(S1,T1),
   reflection(S2,T2).

symmetric(T) :-
  reflection(T,T).

| ?- symmetric(X).
X = leaf
X = node(leaf,leaf)
X = node(node(leaf,leaf),node(leaf,leaf))
X = node(node(leaf,node(leaf,leaf)),node(node(leaf,leaf),leaf))
X = ...
```

I get it up to the point where X is instantiated to leaf and then to node(leaf,leaf), but I can't understand the latter. Please explain, thanks!

Comment: Prolog tries all the possibilities, and starting with `symmetric(X)` it will produce all the combinations of `reflection` with identical nodes as arguments.

Comment: Try to do the some steps of the computation by hand drawing a tree of the possible choices at each step.